# Abstract Over TypeClass

Tags: scala, typeclass

Starting with some simple code:

```
trait Moveable[A] {
  def move(a: A): A
}
trait Animal {
  def kick[A <: Animal: Moveable](a: A): A = implicitly[Moveable[A]] move a
}
object Cat {
  implicit object CatMoveable extends Moveable[Cat] {
    def move(cat: Cat): Cat = cat copy (pos = cat.pos + 4)
  }
}
case class Cat(pos: Int) extends Animal
case class Dog(pos: Int) extends Animal
val someAnimal: Animal = Dog(0)
val kickedCat: Cat = someAnimal kick Cat(0)
println(kickedCat) // Cat(4)
```

I decided to distinguish between, let´s say, `Quadruped` and `Biped` animals:

```
trait FourFeetMoveable[A] {
  def moveWithFourFeets(a: A): A
}
trait TwoFeetMoveable[A] {
  def moveWithTwoFeets(a: A): A
}
trait Animal {
  def kick[A <: Animal /*: ??? */](a: A): A
}
trait Quadruped extends Animal {
  def kick[A <: Animal: FourFeetMoveable](a: A): A = implicitly[FourFeetMoveable[A]] moveWithFourFeets a
}
trait Biped extends Animal {
  def kick[A <: Animal: TwoFeetMoveable](a: A): A = implicitly[TwoFeetMoveable[A]] moveWithTwoFeets a
}
object Chicken {
  implicit object ChickenTwoFeetMoveable extends TwoFeetMoveable[Chicken] {
    def moveWithTwoFeets(chicken: Chicken): Chicken = chicken copy (pos = chicken.pos + 2)
  }
}
case class Dog(pos: Int) extends Quadruped
case class Chicken(pos: Int) extends Biped
val someAnimal: Animal = Dog(0)
val kickedChicken: Chicken = someAnimal kick Chicken(0)
println(kickedChicken) // Chicken(2)
```

A must have is to have two totally different typeclasses `FourFeetMoveable` and `TwoFeetMoveable`, so I **can´t** abstract over them with something like this:

```
trait Moveable[A] {
  def move(a: A): A
}
```

So how can I abstract over the typeclasses used as a context bound at method `kick` in trait `Animal`(see the `???`)?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I should have made my example clearer. Lets say the effect of being kicked can be some movement or some other action. I wanted to abstract over that effect with a typeclass.
In the following code I am showing what I mean and also used an abstract type member `KickingEffect` to abstract over the required typeclass, as [0__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515054/0) proposed:

```
trait StumbleEffect[A <: Animal] {
  def stumble(a: A): A
}
trait GlideEffect[A <: Animal] {
  def glide(a: A): A
}
trait Animal {
  type KickingEffect[A <: Animal]
  def kick[A <: Animal: KickingEffect](a: A): A
}
trait Biped extends Animal {
  type KickingEffect[A <: Animal] = StumbleEffect[A]
  override def kick[A <: Animal: StumbleEffect](a: A): A = implicitly[StumbleEffect[A]] stumble a
}
trait Quadruped extends Animal {
  type KickingEffect[A <: Animal] = GlideEffect[A]
  override def kick[A <: Animal: GlideEffect](a: A): A = implicitly[GlideEffect[A]] glide a
}
object Dog {
  implicit object DogGlideEffect extends GlideEffect[Dog] {
    def glide(dog: Dog): Dog = dog copy (pos = dog.pos + 4)
  }
}
case class Dog(pos: Int) extends Quadruped
case class Cat(pos: Int) extends Quadruped
case class Chicken(pos: Int) extends Biped
```

But then I ran into another problem, when it comes to sequences of animals:

```
type Beast[A <: Animal, KE[_ <: Animal]] = A { type KickingEffect[X <: Animal] = KE[X] }
val dogBeast: Beast[Dog, GlideEffect] = Dog(0) // fine

type GlideBeasts[A <: Quadruped] = Beast[A, GlideEffect]
val glideBeasts: Seq[GlideBeasts[Quadruped]] = Seq(Dog(0), Cat(0)) // fine

def kickAll[A <: Animal, KE[_ <: Animal], KA <: Animal](kicker: Beast[A, KE])(animals: Seq[KA])(implicit ev: kicker.KickingEffect[KA]): Seq[KA] = {
  for (a <- animals) yield kicker kick a
}
val cat = Cat(0)
val dog = Dog(0)
kickAll(cat)(Seq(dog)) // wrong inferred kinds of type arguments
kickAll[Cat, GlideEffect, Dog](cat)(Seq(dog)) // missing implicit evidence
```

Comment: It seems to me that the difference between Biped and Quadruped does not require having two type classes. If both have the same interface, why don't want to just use `Moveable[Chicken]` and `Moveable[Dog]`? In fact, if you have both type classes, no compiler check will stop you from accidentally creating a `TwoFeetMoveable[Dog]`.

Comment: @dyross Sorry my initial example was misleading, see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
trait Moveable[A] {
  def move(a: A): A
}
trait FourFeetMoveable[A] extends Moveable[A]
trait TwoFeetMoveable[A] extends Moveable[A]

trait Animal {
  type CanKick[A] <: Moveable[A]
  def kick[A <: Animal : CanKick](a: A): A = implicitly[CanKick[A]] move a
}
trait Quadruped extends Animal {
  type CanKick[A] = FourFeetMoveable[A]
}
trait Biped extends Animal {
  type CanKick[A] = TwoFeetMoveable[A]
}
```

---

Regarding your **edit**: I would recommend at this point not to further try to model that with types, unless it is really an extremely crucial point in your application or a pure thought experiment. You can get easily overambitious with type-safe design, then the ratio between design effort and application value is getting to big; I would just drop some compile-time safety and go for pattern matching and runtime errors.

If you *do* want to follow the types route, as soon as you have collections, you will need something like [HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to preserve the individual types of the collection members.

---

Anyway, you can make your example work (with explicit type parameters):

```
def kickAll[A <: Animal, KE[_ <: Animal], KA <: Animal](
   kicker: Beast[A, KE])(animals: Seq[KA])(implicit effect: KE[KA]): Seq[KA] = {
      for (a <- animals) yield kicker kick a
}

val cat = Cat(0)
val dog = Dog(0)
kickAll(cat)(Seq(dog)) // still doesn't figure out the types
kickAll[Cat, GlideEffect, Dog](cat)(Seq(dog)) // ok!
```

As said, the tricky or impossible part comes when you try to do this with heterogeneous lists (e.g. requiring different effects). You might get away with using a helper type class for the elements of the sequence, instead, so that implicits can be resolved per item before.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, I found it always useful to *not* introduce type bounds till the moment they are really needed. Not only do you safe a lot of typing (no pun intended), but you keep options open (e.g. for later variance annotations). The following is totally sufficient:

```
trait StumbleEffect[A] {
  def stumble(a: A): A
}
trait GlideEffect[A] {
  def glide(a: A): A
}
trait Animal {
  type KickingEffect[A]
  def kick[A : KickingEffect](a: A): A
}
trait Biped extends Animal {
  type KickingEffect[A] = StumbleEffect[A]
  override def kick[A : StumbleEffect](a: A): A = 
    implicitly[StumbleEffect[A]] stumble a
}
trait Quadruped extends Animal {
  type KickingEffect[A] = GlideEffect[A]
  override def kick[A : GlideEffect](a: A): A = implicitly[GlideEffect[A]] glide a
}
```

etc.